# Counting removed items in a Set in Python

Tags: python

Given two sets

```
a = [5,3,4,1,2,6,7]
b = [1,2,4,9]
c = set(a) - set(b)
# c -> [5,3,6,7]
```

is it possible to count how many items were removed from set 'a' ?

Comment: for the above case 3 items removed from set 'a'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `len(set(a)) - len(c)`?

Edit: `len(a)` could be incorrect if `a` contains duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Fred! That was very simple!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming lack of duplicates:
`len(a)-len(c)`
otherwise try:
`len(set(a)) - len(c)`

Comment: What if you have duplicates ?

Answer (score 3):

there might be a more efficient way, but

```
 len(set(a)-set(c))
```

will work

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [5,3,4,1,2,6,7] 
b = [1,2,4,9] 
c = set(a) - set(b)

print len(c)
```

Comment: This will print size of resultant set. Question refers to something else.